# can't intercept PyDict_New with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: python, c, dlsym, ld-preload

I'm trying to use LD_PRELOAD to intercept the PyDict_New function. I've verified that [this recipe](http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/override.html) workd with getpid in the python interpreter, and I've [adapted it to use PyDict_New](https://gist.github.com/1492306) instead, but it simply doesn't work as I expect. Although I'm clearly allocating dictionaries, and this function must be used, my override isn't being called.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Background: I'm trying to debug a problem in a very large system. I've found that there is a dict with a bad reference count. I know where the dict is first allocated, and where the problem manifests, but I'm pretty certain that the count goes bad at some intermediate time, and a simple code trace won't do, as the dict is cached and re-used (via PyDict_New) by the gc system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LD_PRELOAD can only overload functions that are themselves loaded dynamically.  If you're using the python binary, PyDict_New is not dynamically loaded and therefore there's no way for the dynamic loader to intercept the resolution of that symbol.  If you instead create your own "python" by compiling your own binary and linking with libpython.so, it should work.  Here's what you'd need to put in your program (/tmp/foo.c):

```
#include "Python.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return Py_Main(argc, argv);
}
```

And you can simply build it with:
gcc -o foo -I/usr/include/python2.7 foo.c -lpython2.7

After you do this, LD_PRELOAD on ./foo should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "themselves loaded dynamically". Wouldn't LD_PRELOAD work for overriding global functions in a shared lib not compiled with -Bsymbolic?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that symbols in the executable aren't dynamically loaded by ld.so.  Since they aren't loaded by ld.so, LD_PRELOAD is simply not used.  In this case, the function that the OP wanted to override was compiled into the python executable and not loaded by ld.so from any shared library.  In the solution provided, all of python is dynamically loaded from the libpython2.7.so, so LD_PRELOAD will work.  As for -Bsymbolic, my understanding is that the only effect that would have is to have a library prefer its own symbols first instead of looking at the executable's first.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much easier in your case to just download the source distribution of Python (for the version relevant to you), build it in debug mode and run your application with it.

This method will provide you with much more flexibility in debugging the problem. For example, you can set conditional breakpoints in `PyDict_New` or just replace it with your own version.

Comment: While this doesn't address the question, I'll vote it up. I hadn't thought of that. I guess I'm just not used to working at such a low level.

Comment: @bukzor: your question really doesn't provide enough detail for being directly addressed (show your code, your compilation/linkage/execution paths, the output you expect, the output you see, etc. *otherwise it's currently just too abstract*). That notwithstanding, the approach I propose should get you to debug your problem faster, IMHO

Comment: If you click the links in my post, you'll find all of that information. Maybe I should make them more prominent / explicit. Will do, tomorrow.